# Connection Leak with HikariCP + MySQL + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I'm having a lot of troubles with a Java (tomcat) application using MySQL (Hibernate) and HikariCP as connection pool. I'm having troubles with connection leak, but I'm using Spring's @Transactional annotation in service's and DAO's layers, so I guess shouldn't be a problem.

What's happening: After a while, my application stops. And I can't perform anything that need a database connection. When that happened my logs show:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

The logs that warn leak detection dosn't show any useful tip (to me):

```
295269 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@64f645d5 on thread http-nio-8080-exec-9, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider.getConnection(HikariCPConnectionProvider.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2004)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.isRowAvailable(ListDataModel.java:110)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setRowIndex(ListDataModel.java:185)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setWrappedData(ListDataModel.java:220)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.<init>(ListDataModel.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:583)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.isRowAvailable(UIData.java:343)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:418)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:397)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:629)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:297)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:391)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After a few days trying to fix it, I enabled the debug level for Hikari (I don't know why i didn't this before) and I saw when I perform a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE:

```
54571 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@64f645d5 due to dirty commit state on close().
```

My configurations:

**hibernate.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql"  value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />

<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize" value="350" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" value="2048" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useLocalSessionState" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useLocalTransactionState" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.rewriteBatchedStatements" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cacheServerConfiguration" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.elideSetAutoCommits" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.maintainTimeStats" value="false" />

<!--
    wait_timeout = 1800
idleTimeout, maxLifetime should be 1min less than wait_timeout = 1740s or 1740000ms
 --> 

<property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="200" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="740000" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="1740000" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold" value="60000" /> 

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
```

**MySQL**

```
interactive_timeout = 7200
wait_timeout = 1800
max_connections = 200
```

My code:

**Business Object layer**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Person> getPersons() {
    if (persons == null) {
        try {
            persons = new PersonBO().listAll(Person.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLog().error("Erro", e);
        }
    }
    return persons;
}
```

**DAO layer**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> listAll(Class<E> classEntity) throws Exception {
    return list(createQuery("SELECT o FROM " + classEntity.getSimpleName() + " o"));
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> list(Query query) throws Exception {
    List<E> entities = null;
    if (query != null) {
        try {
            entities = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    return entities;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
private Query createQuery(String jpql) {
    Query query = null;
    if (jpql != null && !jpql.isEmpty()) {
        query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
    }
    return query;
}
```

After stops, I have to restart TOMCAT to start using my system again.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ImO not correct is, that you create the Query in another transaction than where you use it. That should mean, that the orm (hibernate)-session instance where your query is created should be another one than where the Query is used. I think createQuery should be done with Propagation.SUPPORTS or better, don't encapsulate createQuery at all, there is not reason for that, just put `entityManager.` before it. 
On the other side, since you are calling locally, I think in Spring as well as in EJB, the interceptors and therefore the Annotations won't work. ...

Comment: @aschoerk, I didn't understand what was your suggestion about encapsulation, can you give an example?

Also, why interceptors and annotations dosn't work?

Comment: instead of calling the method createQuery use the entityManager directly to create the query. I see no benefit from encapsulating the querycreation into an extra method.

Comment: Oh, It's because there's other methods that use the createQuery. So basically I use the extra method to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I added the `Propagation.SUPPORTS` in all `readOnly = true` but didn't change anything. =/

Comment: Perhaps a Threaddump could show if there are just to many threads and what they are doing. BTW, getting rid of entityManager. imO is no code duplication.